# How to make Chinese thousand-layer cake/bun/bread/mochi that puffs up?

Tags: bread, chinese-cuisine, flatbread

The following video shows a frozen disk grilled for a few minutes and flipped, and the result puffs up 2-3cm/1".  Very nice.  https://www.facebook.com/ccdesan/videos/744030087169350/

Here's a Taiwanese merchant selling them frozen: https://www.owlting.com/market/items/21459

I've known a recipe since the 1980s that is made nearly the same, with sesame oil and green onion, but it makes kind of a nest of straw that doesn't fluff up and would probably be impossible to stuff.  Generally you make a simple Chinese dough with flour and boiling water, roll it out very thin, then roll that up into a log.  You then slice the log in perhaps 2-3cm/1" long sections and roll those flat.  This is a different but similar technique.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MdIVbEgve1A

If anyone has a pointer to a puff-up technique in any language I'd much appreciate it.

Comment: Did you want to share another video? As mentioned in the first paragraph?

Comment: @Stephie I added the "missing link," thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: I‘m afraid but I can’t access the video. You may want to check again.

Comment: @Stephie could you try the link again?  Should now be publicly accessible.

Comment: Sorry, no. I still get an “can’t open, invalid address” pop-up.